# How to disable XAMPP/Apache from returning server IP address along with ServerSignature?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, webserver

I am trying to configure a webserver on **CentOS 6.4** using **XAMPP**.

The only problem I am facing is that I don't seem to find a way to disable the server from returning server IP address along with ServerSignature.

*What I am seeing is below:*

[image]

I have followed various server hardening resources online and have managed to disable ServerSignature, change webmaster email address after editing **httpd.conf**

However I could not find any resource that talks about disabling XAMPP from returning server IP address.
I have tried entering dummy ip in front of ServerName or commenting it out.
[image]

Would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ServerSignature` directive.

Add this to your XAMPP Apache config file (`httpd.conf`):

```
ServerSignature Off
```

With `ServerSignature On`:

[image: With <code>ServerSignature On</code>]

With `ServerSignature Off`:

[image: With <code>ServerSignature Off</code>]

EDIT:

Sorry, I mis-read your question (but I am leaving that "answer" in case it helps anyone else).

I think you might be looking for custom error pages. Check this out:
http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_errors/index.html

It seems that perhaps XAMPP might be using a custom error page is it is still providing server signature information even when using the `ServerSignature Off` directive.

Comment: I wasn't going to use XAMPP in production anyway so I stopped chasing it & configured **httpd**. This problem was solved there. I think there was something with that XAMPP package i was using